# Overcoming System Limits When Using Pivot Table

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I am trying to make a pivot table that has a list of inventory on one axis and customers on another axis.  With this table I could replace all non-'1' values in the table with 1s and then use the column count to determine the total number of items purchased by each customer.  However, Excel claims that there's far too much information and that it wouldn't be able to complete the task.  Is there another way to do this that doesn't involve pivot tables?

Comment: How many rows do you have?

Comment: @pnuts I would definitely try this if it was possible to create the pivot table.

Comment: What version of excel? 2003?

Comment: @Aboba 2013.  I should clarify the error that it gave me had to do with system memory so it may not be a problem with Excel itself.

Comment: Yes, pivot charts are constrained by PC memory size. How is your data structured currently? Is it a list of transactions?

Comment: @Aboba Yep, at the moment it's just a list.

Comment: You may want to just dump the data into Access and run the query there. It's not pretty but it will work.